# Handling error in Pivot source update

Tags: excel, vba

I have create macro to change the source of Pivot in all worksheets. In my workbook there has sheets one with CityName, like 'Mumbai'(Which is pivot sheet) and source data sheet with Name 'MumbaiData'(which is source sheet), It's popping an error bcz sometime i don't have source sheet. How could i handle this Error to resume to next sheet's Pivot

My code

```
Sub pivotsourcechange()


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
ws.PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name & " PV").UsedRange
Next pt
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: To be clear, in the event of the sheet not existing, you do not want the pivot table to be changed at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to use often, but `On Error Resume Next` would work fine here:

```
Sub pivotsourcechange()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim pt As PivotTable

  On Error Resume Next
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
      ws.PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name & " PV").UsedRange
    Next pt
  Next ws
  On Error Goto 0
End Sub
```

There's lots more that can be done with `On Error`, including going to another spot of code to handle the error and returning. Check out this link for info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141571